# Cannot extract value from double quote Perl var with s///

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I'm sure I'm missing something and need another set of eyes.
I've already enabled warnings and use strict
I'm trying to extract the between double quotes in a variable
for example:

```
my $line = '    TITLE "Better off Faded"';
(my $title = $line) =~ s/"(.*?)"/$1/g;

print "title: [$title]\n";
print "MATCHDATA: <$`|$&|$'>\n";
print "capture1: $1\n";
```

This produces the output:

```
title: [    TITLE Better off Faded]
MATCHDATA: <    TITLE |"Better off Faded"|>
capture1: [Better off Faded]
```

It looks like the capture is working, but the substitute command is only removing the double quote characters from the *$title* variable instead of populating it with the *$1* capture.

Since the capture is working, I already know I can use:

```
my $data = ($line =~ /"(.*?)"/)[0];
print "alt: [$date]\n";
```

To extract the data from the double-quotes, but why isn't the substitute working?

Answer (score 3):

The result you're seeing seems consistent with your code.  It matches just the double quoted section and replaces that section with the contents of the quotes, leaving the remainder of the string unchanged.

If your aim is to put just the contents of the quoted section in `$title` perhaps you want something like this:

```
my($title) = $line =~ m/"(.*?)"/;
```

Comment: I can what you've suggested, but I already had a solution for that,  the real question is why the substitution is not working. I see that the substitution IS working, it replaces what is between the first // with what is in the second //  I've been language hopping of late and forgot Perl only changes the part of the string that it matched; it doesn't replace everything in the input string.